# How to import an Excel into SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, import

I'm trying to import an Excel file into SQL Server with this code

```
SELECT Saldos 
FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0',
'Excel 8.0;Database=C:\Martin\Archivos Recibidos\Actuarios\201406 - Saldos.xls')
```

but I get the following error message:

> Msg 7302, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
>   Cannot create an instance of OLE DB provider "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0" for linked server "(null)".

What do I have to do ?

I also tried this code, but the same problem persists:

```
SELECT * 
INTO Saldos 
FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0',
'Excel 8.0;Database=C:\Martin\Archivos Recibidos\Actuarios\201406 - Saldos.xls', 'SELECT * FROM [Customers$]')
```

Martín.

Comment: is your sql server 64bit ?

Comment: yes, my sql server is 64 bit, why?

Comment: You need to install the OLE DB driver on the server that is hosting the SQL instance.  If your SQL Server instance is 64-bit, you need the 64-bit OLE DB driver, which is what I think @M.Ali was getting at.

Comment: BTW, the `Jet.OLEDB.4.0` driver is kind of old.  [You may want to try a newer driver](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24130697/reading-ms-excel-file-from-sql-server-2005/24150349#24150349)

Comment: You got it right @DManson I was getting at this. `Jet.OLEDB.4.0` driver is not supported in SQL Server 64 bit. and this is why you are getting this error. Download newer version of driver I think it is 10 at the moment and this should fix this issue.

Comment: Ok, where can i find it? because im looking for the driver and i cant find it!